# Thread quitting in middle of Method?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I cannot implement workerthreads since there are already too many classes developed with their own threads which call upon methods.  It seems that, if there is any looping code to monitor completion of running threads, the only way to allow the started threads to complete their work is to feed them "sleep" time.  Otherwise, sitting on a WaitOne outside of a thread or attempting anything using a Do-While loop to wait for threads to complete is difficult to successfully perform.

Below is my code which monitors completion of threads in a ThreadList, which works most of the time, however, I traced through breakpoints in a running Method (which was fired via a thread in an instantiated class), and the code simply determined that the thread completed, so execution left the method and continued in the external thread completion-monitoring code.

Do you see any problems in the code below which would cause a thread to falsely signal it was completed, causing execution to leave the For loop below?  Also, will an overabundance of thread sleep time be added to memory using this approach?

```
startagain:
For Each t In threadList
  If t.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped = False Then
     wait(1)
     GoTo startagain
  End If
  If t.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped = True Then Exit For
Next

Private Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Integer)
  For i As Integer = 0 To seconds * 100
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    Application.DoEvents()
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to sleep for one second why don't you just call `Thread.Sleep(1000 * seconds)` instead of that really unnecessary loop? Also, you should _**NEVER**_ use `Application.DoEvents()` like this! It is _**very bad practice**_! Please see: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio's debugger will switch from thread to thread if the breakpoints are there since they run concurrently.  I believe that explains this part of your question "so execution left the method and continued in the external thread completion-monitoring code".

I speculate your problem is that you exit the for loop if a single thread is stopped, yet you are iterating through a list of threads.  **REMOVE** this code and I believe your issue will be resolved:

```
If t.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped = True Then Exit For
```

Finally, here is a [good MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx) that describes different multithreading debugging techniques using Visual Studio.

Comment: That's a great point - didn't think about that!  However, only one thread is run at a time.  Also, ThreadList does not drop the completed threads, so maybe I need to delete the completed threads from the ThreadList?

Comment: One last check, the loop won't quickly "add" many seconds of sleep time that somehow gets built up in memory behind the scenes?  You have to recall, that while threads are running, the For is going to iterate an astronomical number of times -- yes(?), so it is computationally expensive for this loop to keep adding(allowing) numerous seconds of sleep time?  After all, the code does not wait for a second of sleep to end, it just throws out a second over and over again?  Hope you understand my logic.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I would do fewer Sleep calls with a larger interval.  The majority of the computational costs with that code will be because of so much context switching of the threads.

Comment: FYI - Because the outer task loop simply instantiates a lot of classes, I learned that if I just Call each method in the class's constructor (New)  instead of using a thread, I never run into the problem of waiting for threads to finish -- and no errors are thrown.   So is it more efficient to instantiate many classes and call their methods, or instantiate the classes and use threads to fire their methods?  Memory mgmt may be better with a lot of threads running?

Comment: Threading can speed things up with parallelism.  Sometimes it makes sense to do things on a single thread to avoid complexity or because the thread management consumes more cpu time than the benefits it provides.

Comment: That's what I thought - threading speeds up multiple task and optimizes memory usage.